# Could not find the 'Ffmpeg' processor in any of these paths: lib/paperclip, lib/paperclip_processors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Could not find the 'Ffmpeg' processor in any of these paths: lib/paperclip, lib/paperclip_processors

Extracted source (around line #20):
18
19
20
21
22
23

```
def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ffmpeg installed on your system, you can first run `which ffmpeg` to get a path to the executable, i.e. `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`

Then you can symlink that into your project directory.

*bash*: `ln -s /usr/bin/ffmpeg lib/paperclip/ffmpeg`